# Opamp I-V convertor working?

Tags: operational-amplifier

The text says:
"A resistor is the simplest I-to-V converter. However, it has the disadvantage of presenting a nonzero impedance to the source of input current; this can be fatal if the device providing the input current has very little compliance ."

Does the above phrase means that the device which has very little compliance has low output resistance which means that if it is cascaded to an output circuit which contain a resistor as a simplest I-V converter ...the resistor will going to load the device due to its little compliance..since resistor is showing a little resistance enough to load the circuit...

second ..
As the inverting input is maintained at virtual ground..then how can a current can flow in the photo diode branch..how does the circuit the acts as a I-V convertor..

please help...[image]

Answer (score 2):

When they use the term "very little compliance" they mean that the current from the source will vary significantly if the voltage changes even a small amount.

The circuit you show is a basic Transimpedance Converter; The opamp will drive its output to maintain its input at zero volts by normal negative feedback action.  If we assume that no current flows into the opamp input then all the current from the diode has to flow through the feedback resistor (1Megohm in this case). This means that the output voltage is the current from the source multiplied by the value of the feedback resistor. (Thanks OFRBG).

The effective input resistance will be the feedback resistor divided by the gain of the opamp - since that gain may be one million the input resistance can look like a 1 ohm resistor.  If the effective output resistance of the source is 1 kilohm then 99.9% of the source current will go through the feedback resistor and thus generate the output voltage.

Since the voltage at the input is always zero this means that we can measure the current even from sources with little compliance.

A source with little compliance is equivalent to the source have a low value resistor in parallel - if the voltage across the source changes a small amount the current through the resistor changes and takes away some of the source's output current. In the circuit above the opamp doesn't allow any voltage across this parallel resistance and so no current flows through it.  This ensures that all the current from the source flows into the feedback resistor and generates a voltage that can be measured at the output.

As it happens photodiodes have a lot of compliance at DC and the current will change very little for quite a few volts of reverse bias. However they do have significant capacitance and so their compliance is not good at AC.  Using a transimpedance converter can improve response at high frequencies a great amount and such a circuit is almost always used with photodiodes.

Something else to consider is that the normal TIA requires a compensation capacitor across the feedback resistor to ensure stable operation if there is any significant capacitance at the source (e.g. a photodiode).

Comment: To complement the answer for the second question, you may note that, since all the current flows through the resistor, the current will produce a voltage across the resistor. Hence, the *current* input was converted to a *voltage* output.

Comment: @kevin..please elaborate.."Since the voltage at the input is always zero this means that we can measure the current even from sources with little compliance."...i am not able to visualize it..

Comment: @kevin..can it be thought this way that..the high input impedance of opamp does not let the source get loaded by the 1 mohm feedback resistor...??

Comment: That's not the right way of thinking of it.  The opamp will look like a zero ohm input impedance so it doesn't let any voltage build up across the source. But it does ensure that all the current goes through the feedback resistor.

Comment: ok... the main requirement is not letting the current flow through that parallel resistance..in order to do so opamp should show a resistance that should be lower in value to that parallel resistance..hence now in this case the source gets saved from getting loaded by the parallel resistance due to opamp..showing lesser impedance..am i right?

Comment: Yes, you got it.

Comment: but the think that still confuses me is...1. how does opamp appears to be at very low resistance since its input impedance is quite high..2.is the parallel resistance discussed so far.. imaginary?

Comment: That's because of the feedback.  If the source tries to make the voltage at the opamp input go negative a small amount the output goes negative and feeds through the feedback resistor to maintain the zero voltage. A similar thing happens if the source tries to make the input positive. From the source's point of view it acts like it is connected to a very low value resistor.

Comment: Can i think this way ..that the opamp is showing Zero volts..and then the source would compare both the terminal voltage level of the parallel resistance and the opamp and will decide that its better to route the current towards the opamp side ..coz its showing less potential which then can be thought of as it is at low impedance..since low impedance is characterized only when ..when current find a least reisstance to flow path which in this case is provided by opamp which is at zero volts..

Comment: ok...the story is to make the input resistance of the opamp smaller that the output resistance of the source(resistance of parallel resistor)..and this can be only possible by manipulating the value of feedback resistor in reference to the gain of the opamp...